Can std::atomic::wait be used to replace the mutex?
I had this doubt after reading the question C++20 mutex with atomic wait and also Can std::atomic be used sometimes instead of std::mutex in C++? although similar, and my doubt is different, I will explain it below:
I want to know if it is safe to call the std::atomic::wait function to synchronize a piece of code, as many have suggested, it appears that it is possible to use std::atomic::wait, but I believe that perhaps it is not completely safe with risk of a dead-lock occurring
Imagine the following code below:
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::atomic<bool> lock = false;

void go(){
    bool expected = false;
    while(!lock.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) {
        lock.wait(true);
        expected = false;
    }

    std::cout << "Sincronizado" << std::endl;

    lock = false;

    lock.notify_all();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        threads.emplace_back(go);

    for(auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();
}

So far so good, you may have already seen it in several Stackoverflow questions, but now think about the following scenario:
Thread 1: 
+ Win the competition while(!lock.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) 
+ Get to the line before executing lock = false; 
+ Thread 1 is preempted 

Thread 2: 
+ Lose the competition while(!lock.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) 
+ Start executing the line lock.wait(true); 
+ Inside the line (which internally uses Futex) it checks if that lock is true 
+ Still within the line, before blocking begins (FUTEX_WAIT) the thread is preempted 

Thread 1: 
+ Return to execution, and set lock to false. 
+ Notifies all pending threads lock.notify_all(); 

Thread 2: 
+ Return to execution, blocking begins (FUTEX_WAIT)
+ A possible dead-lock? 

Is this scenario possible or am I being paranoid?
I apologize for any confusion, I'm using Google Translate, if you have any questions, please use the comments.
 WAIT !
If my question is incomplete, or is formatted in an inappropriate way, please comment so I can adjust it, thank you in advance, in advance.

Lucas P.

Related: What would it take to implement a mutex using std::atomic? includes a link to https://dept-info.labri.fr/%7Edenis/Enseignement/2008-IR/Articles/01-futex.pdf which shows some algorithms for lightweight mutexes that make no notify system calls in the fast-path (unlock with no waiters, or lock without contention), but still can fall back to .wait / .notify_one without losing any notifications.

For this exact reason, the FUTEX_WAIT system call takes the expected "old" value as an argument.  Before going to sleep, it checks to ensure the futex word still contains this value, and if not, it returns immediately instead of sleeping.
From the futex(2) man page:

FUTEX_WAIT (since Linux 2.6.0)
This operation tests that the value at the futex word
pointed to by the address uaddr still contains the
expected value val, and if so, then sleeps waiting for a
FUTEX_WAKE operation on the futex word.  The load of the
value of the futex word is an atomic memory access (i.e.,
using atomic machine instructions of the respective
architecture).  This load, the comparison with the
expected value, and starting to sleep are performed
atomically and totally ordered with respect to other futex
operations on the same futex word.  If the thread starts
to sleep, it is considered a waiter on this futex word.
If the futex value does not match val, then the call fails
immediately with the error EAGAIN.
The purpose of the comparison with the expected value is   to
prevent lost wake-ups.  If another thread changed the   value of the
futex word after the calling thread decided   to block based on the
prior value, and if the other thread   executed a FUTEX_WAKE operation
(or similar wake-up) after   the value change and before this
FUTEX_WAIT operation,   then the calling thread will observe the value
change and   will not start to sleep.

So in your example, Thread 2 will enter the FUTEX_WAIT system call with val == true.  Since the actual value of lock at this point is false, the futex system call will notice this, and return without going to sleep.  The lock.wait() will then likewise return, giving Thread 2 another chance to execute the compare_exchange and try to take the lock for itself.
Presumably the kernel implements this by tentatively adding the current thread to a list of threads waiting on the futex, and then (after a memory barrier) reloading the futex word.  If it still equals val then we put the thread to sleep.  If not, we remove it from the list of waiters and return.
Thus, assuming another thread is going to modify the value and then call FUTEX_WAKE, we are safe either way.  If we observe the value val, we know that any store of another value happened after our load.  Since we added ourself to the list of waiters before the load, and since any wake event would be signaled after the store, this proves that the wake event would occur after we were on the list of waiters, and so we would not miss it.

You're right, I forgot this detail regarding the implementation of Futex.

See std::atomic::wait:

Performs atomic waiting operations. Behaves as if it repeatedly performs the following steps:

Compare the value representation of this->load(order) with that of old.

If those are equal, then blocks until *this is notified by notify_one() or notify_all(), or the thread is unblocked spuriously.
Otherwise, returns.



These functions are guaranteed to return only if value has changed, even if underlying implementation unblocks spuriously.

The wait is atomic so at worst it'll unblock before you call notify, you'll never miss a notify like you can with a condition variable.

This was one of the main reasons I was opening this question, because I believe that the description of cppreference is confusing, see, in the gcc source code (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/atomic_wait.h) you can see that the call itself is not 100% atomic, (because there is no atomic check + wait operation such as compare + change [CAS]), that is , inside std::atomic::wait a do-while is used and inside the do block there is an if check, if this if is true then blocking is initiated with the Futex system call with the FUTEX_WAIT operation.

This set of operations are not completely atomic, and because of this, despite the statement: "These functions are guaranteed to return only if value has changed" being true, nothing prevents the it from not returning (See the situation I mentioned above in the Post)

I can understand why it is only returned if the value has actually been changed after reading the source code, but I couldn't see where the dead-lock that I suggested in the post is being avoided.

The quote is being missenterpreted(almost read opposite). Notifications are ignored if the value is still old at the decision time. So a good implementation would be to load first and check notification next, iff not possible simultaneously. If a platform intrinsic checks notifications before loading, the behavior must be corrected in the wrapping class; I am not able to figure the cost however.
